# How to access the id of draggable element which is dropped into sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using the JQuery libs to implement drag and drop.

How do I get at the element that is being dragged when it is dropped into sortable list?

I want to get the id of the div being dragged. The following element is dragged:

```
<div class="control" id="control[1]" >
  <img src="img/controls/textfield.png" />
</div>
```

I have the standard dragging function from their example

```
$(".control").draggable({
  connectToSortable: '#sortable',
  helper: 'clone'
});
```

function stop in dragging section with next code return proper value

```
stop: function(event, ui) {
  alert(ui.helper.attr('id'));
}
```

And this is sortable element:

```
<ul id="sortable"><li>test</li></ul>
```

and his function:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
  revert: true,
  accept: '.control',
  receive: function(event, ui) { 
    // here i need to get draggable element id
  }
});
```

I have tried various ui.id etc which doesn't seem to work.

```
receive: function(event, ui) { 
  $(ui.draggable).attr("id")
}
```

throws `undefined`.

---

**Update**:

Sorry, my fault :) As my mother used to tell - "Read API before coding". `ui.item.attr('id')` works fine.

Answer (score 28):

Try

```
receive: function(event, ui) { 
  $(ui.item).attr("id")
}
```

According to the documentation the receive (indeed *all* callbacks for sortable) get two arguments. The second argument should contain:

- ui.helper - the current helper
  element (most often a clone of the
  item)
- ui.position - current position of the
  helper
- ui.offset - current absolute position
  of the helper
- ui.item - the current dragged element
- ui.placeholder - the placeholder (if
  you defined one)
- ui.sender - the sortable where the
  item comes from (only exists if you
  move from one connected list to
  another)

Comment: For a slightly shorter-hand version, instead of this
$(ui.item).attr("id")
you can use this
ui.item.attr("id")

Comment: Thanks for the answer, by the way. I couldn't find any documentation for the attributes of an item or how to access them.

Comment: @MrBoJangles for some reason it's not on jqueryui.com where it would make sense to be.. appears to be [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable)

Answer (score 8):

It seems like the `context` of ui.item changes between the `beforeStop` event and `receive` event.

In my case I'm trying to set the id of the item to a generated value and

```
receive: function (event, ui) { ui.item.attr("id", "control" + currentControlId++);}
```

doesn't work for me

So you can work around this :

```
beforeStop: function (event, ui) { itemContext = ui.item.context;},
receive: function (event, ui) { $(itemContext).attr("id", "control" + currentControlId++);}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been looking all day for this solution!

Comment: This seems like a hack, but does seem to work.  Is this really the best way to handle adding a generated id to a li element upon dropping it into a sortable ul?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, and had troubles accessing the helper element in the start event. What I ended up doing was setting the helper attribute to a function which returned some custom HTML. I was able to access that HTML in the start event without any problems.

```
helper: function() {
    return '<div id="myHelper">This is my custom helper.</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's a problem when you mixing sortables draggables droppables etc.
Make sortable container as droppable as well:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
  revert: true,
  accept: '.control',
  receive: function(event, ui) { 
    // here i need to get draggable element id
  }
});

$('#sortable').droppable({
    accept: '.control',
    drop: function(e, ui){
        var your_draggable_element = $(ui.draggable);
        var your_helper = $(ui.helper);
    }
});
```

that should work

Answer (score 1):

From the jQuery UI draggable docs:

> If you want not just drag, but
>   drag-and-drop, see the jQuery UI
>   Droppable plugin, which provides a
>   drop target for draggables.

See http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7/Droppable

Answer (score 1):

I had success using the **beforeStop** event for the sortable.

From [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-beforeStop)

> **beforeStop**: This event is triggered when sorting stops, but when the placeholder/helper is still available.

```
$( "#something" ).sortable({
  beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
     //you should check if ui.item is indeed the one you want!
     item_id = $(ui.item).attr('id');
     $(ui.item).html('I'm changing the dropped element in the sortable!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit hacky - but worked it out! I have to use $('.dragrow1 li:last')

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom data attribute to store the id of the dragged items. This attribute is still there on the dropped items. The source code as following:

```
<div class="..." data-id="item_id">
    ...
</div>
```

Using `$('dropped item").data('id')` in the sortable to get the id like:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
  ...,
  receive: function(e, ui) { 
      var id = ui.item.data('id');
  }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
  cancel: ".disabledItem",
  items: "li:not(.disabledItem)",
  receive: function(event,ui){

  **var page = ui.item.attr('value');**

  var user = $("#select_users").val();
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation of your solution

Comment: @Brian Tompsett hello, I'm the guy who flagged this as low quality. this is a 2 year old  incomplete post abandoned by OP. Your edit made the post an invalid code block containing markdown stuff which is syntax error. Please don't edit unless it improves the quality without making things worse.